# It is possible to exclude a tag with Behat?

Tags: behat

I know the way to run only the tests tagged with a chosen `@tag`:

```
@invite
Feature: As User I want to invite a friend to join on MySocial

  @mytag
  Scenario: Exists a Facebook user
    Given I go to "/"
    When I follow "Invite a friend"
    ...
```

Is is possible to do exactly the opposite?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to exclude a tag or a list of tags from the command line:

```sh
behat --tags '~@javascript'
```

It is also possible to set excluded (and included) tags in a profile in behat.yml.

**Behat 2.x**

```
default:
  filters:
    tags: "~@wip&&~@postponed&&~@disabled"
```

In the example above I exclude anything that's taged `@wip` (work in progress), `@postponed` or `@disabled`.

**Behat 3.x**

In Behat 3, you can not only configure tags for profiles, but also for suites. The syntax is a bit different:

```
default:
    gherkin:
        filters:
            tags: "~@wip&&~@disabled"

suites:
    admin:
        filters:
            tags: "@admin"
```

**Related docs**

- Behat 2.x:

  - http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html#gherkin-filters
  - http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#filters
- Behat 3.x:

  - http://behat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#global-filters
  - http://behat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/suites.html#suite-filters

Comment: I wonder if you would have a solution [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383870/runing-behat-tests-in-parallel-in-two-browser-windows)?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to just do one tag like Jakub said :

```
behat --tags '~@javascript'
```

if you want to run multiple scenarios with tags like @Done and not @javascript :

```
behat --tags '@Done&&~@javascript'
```

Answer (score 0):

It skips the scenario and feature but it result in error that no scenario found. It should be passed . Is there any way to pass feature having all skipped scenarios executed through command.