# Using @BeforeStep as static method in FeatureContext

Tags: behat, mink

I'm trying to turn `beforeStep()` method into **static** method because I need to use `@BeforeSuite` rather than `@BeforeStep` in annotations. When I do that `$this` become unusable. I did some changes to the original code but getting error below. Any solution to it?

**ERRORS**:

*Line*

```
self::getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
```

*Error*

```
Runtime Notice: Non-static method Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext::getSession() should not be called statically in symfony/src/Site/CommonBundle/Features/Context/FeatureContext.php line 74
```

*Line*

```
self::$session->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
```

*Error*

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSession() on a non-object in symfony/vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/RawMinkContext.php on line 103
```

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
abstract class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    protected $kernel;

    /**
     * @param KernelInterface $kernelInterface Interface for getting Kernel.
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeStep
     */
    public function beforeStep()
    {
        $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^I wait for "([^"]*)" seconds$/
     */
    public function iWaitForGivenSeconds($seconds)
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait($seconds*1000);
    }
}
```

**WHAT I TRIED:**

```
abstract class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    protected $kernel;
    protected static $session;

    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        self::$session = $this->getSession();
    }

    /**
     * @param KernelInterface $kernelInterface Interface for getting Kernel.
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeSuite
     */
    public static function beforeStep()
    {
        // These won't work. First generates error 1 and second generates error 2 as shown above
        self::getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
        self::$session->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^I wait for "([^"]*)" seconds$/
     */
    public function iWaitForGivenSeconds($seconds)
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait($seconds*1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot that those are static when made the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410719/458356) about changing the hook. They are no use for your situation, stick with `@BeforeScenario` – they are the topmost thing that doesn't need to be static. Given you have 5-10 steps per scenario, you are already reducing the number of calls by that number. Not like its the bottleneck anyway…

But if it actually does consume some resources, you can always introduce a static flag in the context:

```
protected static $windowResized;

/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
public function beforeScenario()
{
    if (self::$windowResized) {
        return;
    }

    $this->getSession()->resizeWindow(1440, 900, 'current');
    self::$windowResized = true;
}
```

Comment: I was actually implementing the steps you've given in other post and taking notes per step basis. I'll then add it to same post so others can see how much your suggestions have been helpful. Note: I used `@BeforeScenario` without `static` check cos it is even faster, I think it is because the if statement. Maybe not!

Comment: Cool, please do share the results. One request: try everything without HHVM first (if you are planning giving it a go), see what the difference is, and then try with HHVM. I used it to speedup the Composer during it's worst days, but not the Behat. I had it uninstalled since then, but really want to see the effect on Behat. Installing it on Mac now is rather a painful job.

Comment: I've set HHVM and migrating to Behat 3 to last cos I'll need time for them. Also I couldn't find an example to implement 3rd suggestion. Do you happened to know if there is an example on web somewhere?

Comment: I didn't find anything the last time I searched. I can share some of my code, create a separate question, will be useful for others as well.

Comment: [It is here ....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425623/preventing-user-login-method-running-every-single-time-after-first-login)

Comment: `beforeFeature() must   be a static method`

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith, yes. But this was about scenarios, not features.

Comment: *WOOSH!!!* You missed the forest for the trees!! In Behat 3.0, you cannot have non-static `beforeFeature()` or `beforeScenario()`, therefore your code would not work.

Comment: Perhaps the official [documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/3.hooks.html#scenario-hooks) is wrong?